# Error when opening docker container in vscode in ubuntu

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I am new to coding in containers using docker. I am trying to open a container inside vscode in order to work in the environment. However every time I open the container, it errors out of every time.

1. I am using vscode's docker extension to open the docker file in the cloned repository
2. After trying to launch the file in the container, it errors out and gives me this error code

[image: error_code]

3. I tried rebuilding the container to see if that would work, but it still gives me the same error.

I am really new to working on containers itself, so can anyone help me?

Comment: have you tried running something in the container *not* using vscode? what makes you sure that it's a vscode problem?

Comment: also, [please do not upload images of code, data, or errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead, post the log as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting). images aren't searchable, don't respond to style sheet changes, can't be read by screen readers, take up bandwidth, etc.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't tried opening it in a different IDE, but the container usually works when opening it on windows. I assumed it's either a vscode issue or an ubuntu issue. I'm sorry, I'm very new to asking questions on stack overflow; so I don't know how to format the log in a code block.

Comment: just enclose the ticks in tripple backticks, e.g. `>```<newline>LOG OUTPUT<newline> ```<` - see the guide I sent

Comment: I don't mean a different IDE. I mean running with something like docker desktop, calling `docker run -it image:tag /bin/bash` or something like this

Comment: Here is clearly saying `Container XXX is not running`. Vscode trying to run `/bin/sh` inside stopped container. That is not possible. Probably you have to run container with `-it` arguments